# Bootstrap 4 - Scrollspy not working in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning MVC Core and I'm trying to implement Scrollspy from Bootstrap 4, but it looks like it does not work at all. I have already went through multiple questions in here, but no answer seems to work in my case. That's my first attempt to implement a web application, so I don't assume that I'm doing everything correctly.

My View looks as follows:

```
<div>
    <div class="mainContent" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sideMenu" data-offset="150">
        <div>
            <h3 id="title1">Title 1</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title2">Title 2</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title3">Title  3</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title4">Title 4</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title5">Title 5</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sideBar list-group">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="sideMenu">
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title1">Title 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title2">Title 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title3">Title 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title4">Title 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title5">Title 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS (MainStyles.css):

```
.regionContent {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mainContent {
    margin-right: 300px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.sideBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

My _Layout page (jQuery copied from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js) and pasted to js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Styles/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Styles/MainStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jQuery_v3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Styles/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File structure in wwwroot, which I wasn't sure if it's correct:

```
- wwwroot
-----Scripts
---------jQuery_v3.3.1.js
-----Styles
---------Bootstrap
------------css
---------------bootstrap.css
---------------bootstrap-grid.css
---------------bootstrap-reboot.css
------------js
---------------bootrstrap.js
------------MainStyles.css
```

My Startup.cs has UseStaticFiles() in Configure method. Also referencing js files itself seems to be working, because I have done tests with adding custom js file like this, with some code from w3schools just for testing purpose and it was OK. Yet for some reason scrollspy is not responding to scrolling at all and nothing on the list of titles is marked as active class. I was testing it on Chrome, but lately I also downloaded Firefox Developer Edition and in there, the last position on the list was always marked as active (by default and wasn't changing).

I'd be very grateful for any help and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the [How it works](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/scrollspy/#how-it-works) section:

> Scrollspy requires `position: relative;` on the element you’re spying on, usually the `<body>`.

You can either do that in your CSS:

```
.mainContent {
    position: relative;
}
```

Or you can use one of the utility classes on your div:

```
<div class="mainContent position-relative" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sideMenu" data-offset="150">
```

Additionally, the section also notes:

> When spying on elements other than the `<body>`, be sure to have a height set and `overflow-y: scroll;` applied.

This is not the case with your `.mainContent` area. The snippet below shows your code with these changes applied, and the scrollspy functions correctly. If you don't want to have an explicit height for your `.mainContent` area, you'll need to apply the `data-*` attributes to `body` instead, and ensure that `body` is positioned relative.

```css
.regionContent {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mainContent {
    margin-right: 300px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    
    /* CSS required to make it work */
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.sideBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; /* moved to top for sake of example display in iframe */
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div class="mainContent" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sideMenu">
        <div>
            <h3 id="title1">Title 1</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title2">Title 2</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title3">Title  3</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title4">Title 4</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 id="title5">Title 5</h3>
            <div class="regionContent">
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sideBar list-group">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="sideMenu">
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title1">Title 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title2">Title 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title3">Title 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title4">Title 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#title5">Title 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It finally works, thank you! I have applied it a bit differently to utilize your tips a bit better. I have changed my ID sideMenu to a class and then moved the data-* tags to body section in _Layout as you have said. Also added relative position to body tag and it works. Just one weird thing I have noticed about it... Let's say I have 5 titles in my View and when I scroll to the bottom, I can see last 3 ones on my screen. Scrollspy makes the last one active then, not the 3rd one from the top, as I'd expect it to do. I guess it's just how it supposes to work, right?

Comment: The Bootstrap examples work the same way. Scollspy marks the last visible item in the list as active. Therefore, if you're at the bottom with previous items still visible, the last item is going to be active.